# how to use python "get()" for keys deeper than first level of dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary that has more than 2 levels, something like this:

```
dict = {'keyA_1':'valueA_1', 'keyB_1': {'keyB_2':{'keyB_3':'valueB_3'}}}
```

I wish to extract the value of `'keyA_1'` and `'keyB_3'`. However, in my code, I do not want to use a bunch of `try/except KeyError` for error checking as I have thousands of key-value pairs. Instead, if the key does not exist, simply returns None. One solution I found is to use python `get()`. This works nicely but only for first level key-value pair.

For example, if `'keyA_1'` does not exist

```
dict.get('keyA_1')
```

would return `None`

But if `'keyB_3'` does not exist

```
dict.get('keyB_1').get('keyB_2').get('keyB_3')
```

would return `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` instead of `None`

It would be great to simply do the same for `'keyB_3'` where it returns the value if all parent keys and its key exist else return `None`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass a default value as the second argument to `dict.get()`, like this:

```
dict.get('keyB_1', {}).get('keyB_2', {}).get('keyB_3')
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer works, but is way too much inline code. Here's a version that's easy to use:

```
# Usage: dot_get(mydict, 'some.deeply.nested.value', 'my default')
def dot_get(_dict, path, default=None):
  for key in path.split('.'):
    try:
      _dict = _dict[key]
    except KeyError:
      return default
  return _dict
```

Easiest use:
`retrieved_value = dot_get('some.deeply.nested.value')`